# Computing a trigonometric sum

Tags: trigonometry, summation

I am asked to solve the following problem

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{\sin^3{(3^n)}}{3^n}}$$

My work:

Using the identity $\sin{(3x)}=3\sin x-4\sin^3x$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{\sin^3{(3^n)}}{3^n}}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{3\sin 3^n-\sin{3^{n+1}}}{3^n}}$$

From here I do not know how to procede, even tough it looks like it is a telescoping series, I cannot find a way to arrive at it.

I also tried:

$$n\rightarrow3^n\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin^3{n}}{n}}\\
\text{Applying the identity}\\
\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{3\sin n-\sin{n}}{n}}$$

Which again looks like it might telescope, but I do not see how to arrive at the result.

Any help, hint or solution is welcome!